# Ruby extract-testcases.rb:172:in `<main>': undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby. How can I fix this error

This is the 172 line

us_headers =  all_subtasks.first.keys

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/aaprasad/kKX8r) is the link to the code Snippet.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question, like a snippet from your code.

Comment: Please check this https://bitbucket.org/snippets/aaprasad/kKX8r

Comment: I just edited your question and added the link. Edit pending review...

Comment: Thanks ! Were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

`keys` is a method of `Hash` class. This error occurs because `first` returns `nil`. So, `all_subtasks` returns an empty array, `[]`.

Comment: Thanks but need more help.. Added the snippet